# Render Glossy indirect and Shadow pass without the use of ViewLayers

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes, viewlayers

I'm wondering if there exists a solution that allows you to render the Shadow Pass and Glossy Indirect pass in the same render/view layer, on the same plane and still have a transparent background.

What I'm trying to do is to Render a colour pass, a shadow pass and a **ground** reflection pass for a complex metal machine. That means I don't want the glossy indirect pass from the machine itself (I currently set it to holdout and indirect only), just the reflections of the ground plane the machine produces.

There are several problems with this approach I'm facing.

First is the Shadow Pass and the Glossy Indirect. If you set the ground plane to be the Shadow Catcher it won't get any reflections in the Glossy Indirect pass, which makes sense because it catches only shadows. If you put another plane as a reflection catcher plane just slightly below the Shadow Catcher, it's not visible and if you put it above you don't get shadows on the shadow catcher but you get them on the reflections catcher.

The second problem is the colour. If I want to have the Glossy indirect pass, I have to have the ground plane visible, which I don't want. I want to have the object on a transparent plane.

The way I'm handling this now is that I create 2 view layers, set up catcher planes into separate collections and enable/disable them according to each view layer so they won't overlap and cause the problems mentioned above. Then I effectively have to render the same frame twice where I collect the color and shadow pass from 1 render and the Indirect pass from the other one.

In short, is there a solution that provides the same functionality as the Shadow Catcher but for Glossy Indirect pass and would work with the Shadow Catcher? And if not, would it be theoretically possible to program something like it?

I will give an example of the render passes I would like to have as a result.

[image: Color pass]

[image: Glossy Indirect pass]

[image: Shadow Catcher pass]